# How can I fetch the data of specific month from SQLite database

Tags: java, android, database, datetime, sqlite

I saved my data In SQLite Database.
I saved my date in database as DATETIME datatype.

I want to retrive only the data of specific month from my SQLite databse.

I try the below query to retrive data, but it was not useful. It gives me data but it was not the specific month.

```
SELECT coulumn_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name Between "MM-DD-YYYY" AND "MM-DD-YYYY"
```

Comment: did you try with your dates in format "yyyy-mm-dd"?

Comment: No I don't try it...because I want only this format of date...I now I try, Its worked or not.

Comment: The core problem with the `MM-DD-YYYY` is that it is not lexicographically ordered with respect to continuous time-spans. This is why it is a good reason to use ISO 8601 date/times in general :-) [SQLite also supports ISO 8601 with minimal effort]

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/33657233/8905812

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably not optimal, but you could use:

```
select column_name from table_name where strftime('%Y-%m', column_name) = '2011-05';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a function retrieve only the month of the date 
`SELECT strftime('%m', date(column_name)) FROM table;`

I believe this is the function, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: +1 But might need to take Year into account (I gave a +1 because the question is sort of vague in the area). The function should also be moved into the `WHERE`.