# Get values from database by month in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database where I have a table:
[image]

I want to get all the values for the month 11 - November. 
I created something like:

```
public static List<Plan> getPlanListByMonth(SQLiteDatabase db, DateTime date) {

        String where = "strftime('%m', '"+"date"+"') = " +
                "'"+"11"+"'";

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, where,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        return getPlanList(cursor);
    }

    private static List<Plan> getPlanList(Cursor cursor) {

        List<Plan> PlanList = null;

        if (cursor != null) {

            PlanList = new ArrayList<>();

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                do {
                    Object obj = getPlan(cursor);
                    PlanList.add((Plan) obj);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();
        }

        return PlanList;
    }
```

But no effect. Any idea about how get all values by month?

Comment: I copy paste your String. This is how look query in debugger: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM workoutPlan WHERE strftime('%m', '2015-11-30') = 11

Comment: this is actual query: SQLiteDirectCursorDriver: SELECT * FROM workoutPlan WHERE strftime('%m', date) = 11 and no effect

Comment: Yes! Finally! Thank you a lot! You are my hero :D

Comment: Sometimes the easiest traps to fall into are under our nose, uh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh well.

Change your query to read

```
SELECT * FROM workoutPlan WHERE strftime('%m', date) = '11'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM workoutPlan WHERE CAST((strftime('%m', date)) AS INTEGER) = 11
```

And that's all.