# SQLite filter records by month/year

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I used the `dumpCursor()` method to verify if the db contains the proper values
But when I run:

```
myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME +" WHERE YEAR(date) = 2015", null);
```

(the date column is defined as  "datetime DEFAULT NULL")
I get an uncaught exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: not sure how to use this debug tool..

Comment: ok found it: 11-13 10:21:58.044 9364-9364/com.example.spuser.drawer E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such function: YEAR

Comment: I answered a similar question some days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33657233/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered a similar question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33657233/2649012

The key is using the `strftime()` function.
The parameter to pass is `'%m'` for a monthly search or `'%Y'` for a yearly search.

Therefore, change your query to

```
myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME +" WHERE strfttime('%Y', date) = '2015'", null);
```

Comment: Yes: **str**ing **f**orma**t** **time**.

Comment: The solution worked but there are some typos ->  strftime('%Y', date) "

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have the `YEAR` function found in other flavors of SQL. The available date & time functions are listed [on this page](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Depending on how your date are stored, you may have to do something like simple substring extraction (using the `SUBSTR` function) on your column value, for example.

Comment: i am sure there's a better way to extract month filed.parsing is not a solution, i use datetime type and not text so this should be used..

Comment: @OriCohen see my edit, it depends how your date is stored. If you need some strategies for this, please give a little more information about how you are storing your dates.

Comment: this is how it's stored: date=2015-11-13 08:44:30